# How can I change a table column's size and its text justification at the same time in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, fonts, width

I am a newbie in LaTeX but I know that this command

```
{|>{\small} l | p{2.8cm} | p{2.93cm} | p{2.85 cm} | p{2.58 cm} | }
```

will change first column justification to left and set the size for other columns. I need left justification and small font with adjusted column size for all

```
|>{\small} l p{2.8cm} |
```

is not working. What should I try?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `tabularx` package with the `X` column specifier?  For more details, you can look at the [Tables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) wiki page.

To deal with the font size, you could use the `\captionsetup` command, which can be called in the preamble (to set globally) or inside the `\begin{table}` environment (to set locally).

Answer (score 1):

That specification will set `\small` just for the first column.

The simplest way for setting `\small` for the entire table is to set it *outside* the `tabular`.

If you want all columns to be raggedright, the simplest way is to define a new column type:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}

{\small\begin{tabular}{ | l | L{2.8cm} | L{2.93cm} | L{2.85cm} | L{2.58cm} | }
...
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fixed by breaking the lines using \wrap{} which was suggested here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102684/how-to-create-a-new-line-in-the-table-cell